# How can i pass express Request and Response objects into graphql-yoga context using the createYoga function?

Tags: express, graphql, graphql-yoga

I want to pass the express `req` and `res` object to my context because i want to use `express-sessions` to do session-based-auth because the default `requests` from the context does not know about sessions. Here is what I have tried

```
app.use("/graphql", (req, res) => {
    return createYoga({
      context: ({ params }) => {
        return {
          req,
          params,
          res,
          prisma,
          redis: redisClient,
        };
      },
      graphiql: true,
      landingPage: false,
      cors: false,
      schema,
    });
});
```

But if i try this it seems like the request is not going through.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/features/context#server-context), while running in node.js and express runtime, the context will automatically have the request and response.

> Server Context
>
> When creating the server instance, GraphQL Yoga accepts an additional
> object from your base server framework or library that will be merged
> with the default context. Node.js (standalone, express and Next.js
> etc.)
>
> If you are using GraphQL Yoga as a standalone server with createServer
> from the http(s) module or exposing it as a middleware as we show in
> the express or Next.js integration recipes.
>
> ```
> req - Node.js IncomingMessage object
> res - Node.js ServerResponse object
> ```
>
> The req and res objects are added to the initial context object.
>
> const serverContext = { ...defaultContext, req, res }
>
> Thus, when using @graphql-yoga/node, it is possible to access
> context.req and context.res within the GraphQL resolvers or the user
> context factory function.
>
> However, we recommend avoiding using context.req and context.res
> wherever possible and instead favor context.request, as it is more
> future-proof and platform independent (as Node.js HTTP servers adopt
> the Fetch Response API).

I did try this out and the context does have the req and res objects.
[image: req and res present while running in node.js and express.]